# Two properties that relate to each other in another model

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

Sorry that the title might be confusing but I'm not native english speaker and very new to django terms.

I have a scenario like this: A department can have many branches. I have a student model where he has two properties, Department and Branch.

When I select his department , I want it to accept (and show in admin panel) only the branches that are related to that department , my code so far is this:

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True , default = uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    

class Department(Entity):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)


class Branch(Entity):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    dep = models.ForeignKey(Department, related_name='branches', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Student(Entity):
    #Some Fields here
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, related_name='students', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch, related_name='students', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Assuming I have a 2 departments (CE and CS), CE has 2 branches and CS has 3 branches , What I want is, when I choose a student's department in the admin panel, I want the branches to be shown (to select from)  only the one that exists on that department , what I'm getting is 5 branches (in this example).

How can I solve this ?

NOTE: I haven't played with anything related to the admin panel except registering the models.
Thanks in advance and sorry if the title or any other part is not very correct.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions:

1. override save() function and check branch.
2. Check branch inside form by overriding clean_branch()

It's better to implement both.

Comment: Thanks for answering and appreciated so much. Can you give a little bit more details ? like just the first steps cause I'm very new to django and python overall to be honest and couldn't understand what you mean exactly. The thing is in `website/admin` I mean in the panel , when adding new student , how can I make the branch show only the ones that related to the branch selected above it ?

Comment: Alright, django models have save() method that are called when new or updating data are getting saved. so you can override save method and check if branch belongs to department call super save method else throw exception. And inside forms you can clean all fields by overriding its method. for example clean_branch() validates branch:

Comment: Check this links: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-form
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#customizing-model-loading